# Repeat Query Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, select

I wrote sql query :

```
SELECT d.nazw FROM gru u JOIN swd d USING(nswd)
WHERE u.ngru = :data::bigint AND :type::text = 'group'
UNION ALL 
SELECT nazw as PORTAL FROM wsu
WHERE prtl = :data::bigint AND :type::text = 'portal'
UNION ALL 
SELECT nazw FROM swd
WHERE nswd = :data::bigint AND :type::text = 'nswd'
```

In my java app i have Hashmap like : <"portal",21>, <"nswd, 10"> etc. How can i repeat this query multiple times and get result as map or something similar like <nswd-10, RESULT> ?

I can get result for one select, but i don't know hot to do this automatically

Comment: Note that your column alias in the second query ( `as portal`)  has no effect. The column names for the complete result of a UNION are determined by the _first_ query.

Comment: Yep, i already deleted it in query :)